# Update multiple tables with single query

Tags: mysql, sql

All three tables are different. The only thing they have in common is `id`, and `image`

This query works only if there are rows in each table.

What's the best way of doing it? Please don't saw use prepared statements. That's on my ToDo list already :)

```
UPDATE subcontent, products, content
SET subcontent.image = NULL, products.image = NULL, content.image = NULL
WHERE subcontent.image = 3
OR products.image = 3
OR content.image = 'test.png'
```

I tried using `LEFT JOIN` but doesn't work either. Is the query wrong?

```
UPDATE content
LEFT JOIN subcontent on
    subcontent.image = content.image
LEFT JOIN products on
    products.image = content.image
SET content.image = NULL, subcontent.image = NULL, products.image = NULL
WHERE content.image = 'test.png'
OR subcontent.image = 3
OR products.image = 3
```

Answer (score 1):

How about three separate updates?

```
UPDATE subcontent
   SET subcontent.image = NULL
   WHERE subcontent.image = 3;

UPDATE products
   SET products.image = NULL
   WHERE products.image = 3;

UPDATE content
   SET content.image = NULL
   WHERE content.image = 'test.png';
```

The problem you have with attempting a multi-table update is that this uses a `join`.  Alas, if one of the tables is empty, then the joining will return no rows in any table to be updates.  You can use a `left join`, but then you have to assume that the first table is not empty.  And, MySQL doesn't support a full outer join.

Three separate updates is probably the simplest method.

Comment: Hm, I'll look into `LEFT JOIN` because the `content` table with NEVER be empty.

Comment: Doesn't look like `LEFT JOIN` works either, but I could be doing it wrong. I put the query in my original post, if you can take a look.

Comment: @Draven . . . That is obviously not going to do what you want.  The `image` field seems to contain a character string in `content` but a number in the other two tables.  I would stick with the three separate queries.